# Execute bash command inside fish function

Tags: fish

I decided to try fish shell, and I'm having trouble with some aliases. So I guess the painless way of doing the things would be executing the bash commands inside fish shell functions. Something like that :

```
function fish_function
start bash
    ... bash commands ... 
stop bash
end
```

Is that possible?

e.g: the command

```
pacman -Qtdq && sudo pacman -Rns $(pacman -Qtdq)
```

doesn't work in fish shell and I have no idea how to convert this

Comment: I read that fish uses `()` for command subsitutions. Just try to remove the `$`.

Comment: worked ! (after substituting '&&' for ';and')

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Apparently](https://fishshell.com/docs/current/tutorial.html#tut_command_substitutions) fish uses `; and` for `&&` and `()` for command substitutions.

So just changing the command to

```bsh
pacman -Qtdq; and sudo pacman -Rns (pacman -Qtdq)
```

should work.

---

Answering the actual question, normally you can get a statement to be executed in Bash simply by redirecting the statement to a `bash` command's STDIN by any mean (notice that I'm on Zsh, which supports here strings, and that the statement prints the content of a Bash-specific variable):

```bsh
% <<<'echo $BASH' bash
/bin/bash
```

However as a general rule I'd suggest to use `bash`'s `-c` option. For example here strings and pipes don't play too well with multiple commands, here documents will be expanded by the current shell, etc (nevertheless those need to be supported by the current shell).

Overall `bash -c` seems to be always a safe bet:

```bsh
bash -c 'pacman -Qtdq && sudo pacman -Rns $(pacman -Qtdq)'
```

Which for multiple commands becomes something like this:

```bsh
bash -c '
command1
command2
command3
'
```